# How can i filter on this dataframe such that i take where column value is null?

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following table:

```
client_id | acquiring_date | transaction | date 
----------+----------------+-------------+-------
123       |    202305      |   200       | 202306
123       |    202305      |   200       | 202206
123       |    202305      |   200       | 202203
123       |    202305      |   200       | 202201
789       |                |   20        | 202202
890       |                |   310       | 202201
```

This table contains clients ids and transactions by date, the acquiring date corresponds to when this client was acquired by my company. i have this table and i want to filter on those transactions in the 12 months before the acquiring_date irrespective of the client id. e.g.

```
select * 
from df
where date >= acquiring_date - 100 
  and date < acquiring_date
```

However this only returns me values where `acquiring_date` is `NOT NULL`, so it doesn't pick up the dates in last two rows.

How can I rewrite this such that it picks up the last two rows as well?

I am using SQL within hive

Answer (score 0):

You can include an "is null" check for the column.

Multiple conditions can be considered in a where clause with an "or".

```
select * 
from df
where acquiring_date is null or 
  (date >= acquiring_date - 100 and date < acquiring_date)
```

In the above example, all records that qualify for **either** of these will be returned:

- acquiring_date is null
- date is before acquiring_date and after acquiring_date minus 101 days

Comment: hi but i still need to check that where acquiriing date is NULL the acqiruing date is within those bounds i specified

Comment: If the acquiring date is null, then it can't be within any bounds. You would need to find a way to populate it first.